# JavaScript - shuffling audio

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, audio, shuffle

I am creating a webpage that uses JavaScript to shuffle a series of audio file questions and their matching drag-and-drop answers. I have successfully implemented this using the native HTML5 audio tags but also have a fallback section for IE 7/8 since these browsers cannot read the audio tag. This fallback section uses conditional comments around object and param tags as demonstrated [at the end of this article here](http://www.elated.com/articles/html5-audio/).

It works in that it does shuffle in IE, but breaks in that it displays the ugly Media Player-style controls that I had specifically hidden, as this activity uses "play sound" buttons instead of audio player controls.

If anyone needs to see specific parts of code, just let me know.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh... just noticed another issue... the shuffle function on the fallback <object> and <param> kills the audio - i.e. it won't play when you click on the buttons in IE. Any suggestions from the whizzes out there? Thanks again :)

Comment: Issue with IE sound and shuffle solved below for those with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts (sorry, I'm on a mac at the moment so testing in IE isn't a great option):

1. I see the parameters where you're trying to hide the controls, but have you also tried applying css to the object tag or to a container wrapped around it?  It might be as simple as giving a wrapper div a style of `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.
2. This isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you investigated any plugins such as [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)?  It uses HTML5 audio with a Flash fallback; I've used it before and had success.  Obviously it requires Flash on older browsers, but if that's not an issue it could be easier than trying to figure out how to hide the controls.

It's a nice little page by the way.  Good luck!

To address your second question/comment: using an object/embed tag means that you're relying on the browser/OS deciding on what plugin it will use to play audio. Some Googling turns up issues with IE and quicktime, and one possible solution:

- [Jan 2009 Microsoft update breaks mp3 sound objects in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574565/jan-2009-microsoft-update-breaks-mp3-sound-objects-in-ie7)
- [IE issues with quicktime](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/d167789c-98e8-4dbf-b9fa-3544affd43a3/)

Hope it helps.  SoundManager 2 might be worth trying if you keep hitting walls, just be aware that using SM2 will mandate that users with older browsers have Flash installed and unblocked.

Comment: Woohoo! You little ripper! Thanks - it was indeed as easy as setting the CSS display property of the <object> to none.

Comment: Edited my question to provide more feedback on your follow-up question, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions :) Managed to work the second part out - see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve managed to out the second issue with the audio in IE – for the shuffle script to work with the audio in IE, you have to call the shuffle BEFORE the audio code – in my case I moved all the conditional comments below the `.shuffle();` stuff and it works no worries!